# Is this graph problem already solved

Tags: graph-theory, problem-solving

I would like to solve the following:

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph such as $\forall (x,y) \in E, x \neq y$.

Find any (all would be even better) graphs $S$ such that:

- $S \subset V$
- $\#\{(x,y) \mid (x,y) \in E, x \not \in S, y \in S\} \leq k \times \#S$

where $k$ is a strictly-positive rational.

In short, what I need to find is subsets $S$ of the graph’s variables which have less edges going from $V \setminus S $ to $S$ than some $k$ times their size. The idea is to find “relatively isolated” subsets of the graph’s variables.

Before starting to work on a solving algorithm, I wondered if the problem had already been solved, but I don’t really know what keywords to search for.

Alternatively, if the problem hasn’t arleady been solved, I don’t have any idea as to where to start. Perhaps starting with the naïve algorithm that tries all subsets and then try to look through the “good ones” first ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may search for expander graphs.   You can start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph